# I have create a custom directive (dynamic form template), which is create by a object. I am not able to get form data in my controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have create custom directive. directive having a template file which create a custom from help with the help of a object pass by controller. I am not able to get form data in my controller.

```
app.directive('tab', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl : 'template.html',
      scope : {
          data : '='
      },

      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      },
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs',
         function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.updateEntity = function(){
                  $scope.formData = '';
              };
          }
       ]
  };
```

});

```
<tab data = "form"></tab>
```

**plnkr** for this [click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpblB6365kEhePqnSlUm?p=preview)

Comment: Could you clearify your question ? its realy not clear what you do

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan I want to create a custom directive, its consume a object which present in my controller. Depending upon my object custom directive rendered (how many and which type filed show on UI).
problem is that i am not able to get these fileds data in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you suddenly start using ng-model="entity[...]".
Try this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="element in data">
            <label class="control-label">{{element.label}}</label>
            <div class="controls" ng-switch="element.widget">
                <input ng-switch-when="text" type="text" ng-model="element.model" ng-required="element.required" />
                <select ng-switch-when="select" ng-model="element.model" ng-required="element.required" ng-options="o.key as o.name for o in element.options"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="updateEntity()">Get Data</button>
</form>
```

If you want your dropdownlist to have a default value of i.e. French set your model like this

```
language: {
    label: 'Language',
    model: 'fr',
    ...
}
```